# Extract nested Python dictionary from complex string

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nested

I have a complex string with a nested dictionary in it. This dictionary further has a list of three similar dictionaries inside it. How do I convert this into a Python dictionary? Please help.

Input: `'name: "data dict" id: 2\nv6: false\nstats {\n  hosts {\n    cnt1: 256\n    cnt2: 0\n  }\n  groups {\n    cnt1: 1\n    cnt2: 0\n  }\n  main_groups {\n    cnt1: 1\n    cnt2: 0\n  }\n  main_hosts {\n    cnt1: 256\n    cnt2: 0\n  }\n}\n group_id: "None"'`

Expected result: `{
name: "data dict",
id: 2,
v6: false,
stats: {
    hosts: {
        cnt: 1, cnt: 2
    }
    groups: {
        cnt: 1, cnt: 2
    }
    main: {
        cnt: 1, cnt: 2
    }
  main_hosts: {
    cnt: 1, cnt: 2
    }
}
}`

Comment: How did this string come to be??? This looks like it could have been a JSON at some point. Probably easiest to fix whatever is extracting this mess to extract the valid JSON...

Comment: I don't think I'd use a `regex`. I'm a fan of [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) for tasks like this.

Comment: can you show the string formatted, looks like a yaml, then yaml module will do conversion

Comment: you will need massage it into valid  yaml (or json) by inserting semicolons before {, line break between " and space (comma for json) then use yaml (or json) module

Answer (score 1):

As TS mentioned, there are a string with a nested dictionary (first time I interpret it as an implicit reference to validity). If the string content is **valid** JSON you can use `json` built-in package includes all you need to parse it:

```
import json
data = json.loads(your_string)
```

Read more in [JSON package docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

If not, you can write regular expression or use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) package to process this string.

Comment: This will not work because the original string is not properly formatted json

Comment: Look again, this will not work... the string is not valid JSON.

Comment: It is not valid JSON. Did you even try it?

Comment: oh, sorry, I miss this thing. I'll correct the answer in a minute

Comment: I've updated this with suggestions that covers both valid JSON or not. Still not sure isn't it better to remove the answer

Answer (score 0):

With some editing of your input, it can be loaded by `yaml` and the data object is as you have requested it, a set of nested dictionaries.
How was the input string created ?. The specific edits are :

- change "data dict" id:" to "data dict"\nid:",
- change "\n group_id" to  "\ngroup_id"
- change all { to : ,
- remove all } .